# Counting the number of "Nines", "Threes" and "Ones" in an integer between 0 and 26

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I came across a problem and I was unable to find a solution for it over the net. Maybe I wasn't entering in the right words for the accurate search. However, the problem goes like this:

Find how many of Nines, Threes and Ones it would take when added together to reach the given integer. When also multiplied by 1, 3 and 9.

In other words, say n = 25, we will then have 2 (Nines), 2 (Threes) and 1 (Ones). When we multiply them

2 * 9 = 18

2 * 3 = 6

1 * 1 = 1

total = 18 + 6 + 1 = 25 = n.

I was able to find a solution; however I was wondering if there's a smaller version of the same.

Here's my code.

```
def one_3_9(num):
    temp = num
    threes = []
    ones = []
    nines = []
    val_ = 0

    while temp != 0:
        if 0 < num <=8:
           if num >= 3:
               val_ = num // 3
               threes.append(val_)
               temp = temp - (3 * val_)
               ones.append(temp)
               temp = temp - temp
           elif num < 3:
               ones.append(num)
               temp = temp - temp

        if 26 >= num >= 9:
            val_ = num // 9
            nines.append(val_)
            temp = temp - (9 * val_)
            ones.append(temp)
            temp = temp - temp
            if temp >= 3:
                num = temp
                val_ = num // 3
                threes.append(val_)
                temp = temp - (3 * val_)
                ones.append(temp)
                temp = temp - temp
       else:
           print("Number Should be more than 0 and less than 26.")
           break
   print("threes: ", threes)
   print("Ones : ", ones)
   print("nines: ", nines)
```

I completely AGREE the answer is long-winded and perhaps so is my explanation. However, I really hope I make sense with this example.

Thank you.

Comment: Convert your number to base 3 and those digits are your answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is calculating the three digits of your number in base 3, assuming it's less than 27.

Here is some simpler code:

```
def one_3_9(num):
    nines = num // 9
    threes = (num%9) // 3
    ones = num % 3
    print("Nines:", nines)
    print("Threes:", threes)
    print("Ones:", ones)
```

Comment: No problem. You don't need to thank or follow people: this isn't a social media site. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the values in descending order, use modulus division to find how many times it can go into the value and subtract that result from your running value:

```
def goes_into(n, vals):
    result = {}
    for i in sorted(vals, reverse=True):
        into = n // i
        result[i] = into
        n -= i * into
    if n % i:
        raise ValueError("n is not attainable by vals")
    return result
```

---

```
>>> goes_into(25, [1, 3, 9])
{9: 2, 3: 2, 1: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the approaches:

```
def calculate(num):
    nines = num//9
    threes = (num-(9*nines))//3
    ones = num - (9*nines) - (3*threes)
    print (f'{num} requires: 9s: {nines}, 3s: {threes}, 1s: {ones}')
    
calculate(49)
calculate(25)
calculate(37)
```

Output:

```
49 requires: 9s: 5, 3s: 1, 1s: 1
25 requires: 9s: 2, 3s: 2, 1s: 1
37 requires: 9s: 4, 3s: 0, 1s: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have made another attempt myself on the answer, basically it is very similar to my earlier answer within the question. It's more of editing which is done within the code itself.

```
def ones_threes_nines(num):
    val = 0
    nines = []
    threes = []
    ones = []

    if num > 0 and num <= 26:
        val = num // 9
        nines.append(val)
        num = num - (val*9)
        val = num // 3
        threes.append(val)
        num = num - (val*3)
        ones.append(num) 
    else:
        print("Number should be more than 0 ")
    print("Nines: ", nines, "Threes: ", threes, "Ones : ", ones)
```

This is just an attempt on improving from my earlier answer, that mainly includes editing and slight improvements. Which I hope is in line with the question itself of getting a shorter version of the answer.